# Highcharts custom export hidding on Reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am facing one issue with the highcharts.

I have this code which renders the custom download instead of highcharts default print and download :

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
    exporting: {
                            buttons: {
                                contextButton: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                exportButton: {
                                    text: 'Download',
                                    y:30,
                                    //x: 1,
                                    //y: 5,
                                    // Use only the download related menu items from the default context button
                                    menuItems: Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.splice(2)
                                },
                                printButton: {
                                    text: 'Print',
                                    y: 30,
                                    onclick: function () {
                                        this.print();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
       });
```

This code is working fine when I call it once, but when I call it again without refreshing the page, the download button does not show me all the options such as download as pdf, download as image etc.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is the culprit:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.splice(2)
```

`splice` modifies array. So after first call, `menuItems` isn't the same. So use `slice()` instead:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.slice(2)
```